# Изменение текста на jQuery

Tags: jquery

Есть строка: `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index_files/styles_m.сss" media="all">`

Нужно изменить "styles_m.сss" на "styles.сss".

Comment: самому стало интересно. сижу гуглю. можно попробовать так:
document.head.innerHTML += "<link rel='testtest' type='test' href='test.css'>";

--попробуйте так. это добавит в конец стиль и он перебьет предыдущую css

или... гуглить))

Comment: А руками изменить религия не позволяет :) выглядит не как велосипед, а как первое колесо на планете.

Comment: Если есть возможность добавить id к *линку*, то вообще без проблем.  
В обратном случае *парсить* все теги *link*, сверять их значение с *index_files/styles_m.сss* и потом заменять параметр *href*
_____
Либо, если точно знаете позицию нужного *link*:

    var link = document.getElementsByTagName('link')[0]
    link.href="styles.сss";